# Webpack when using readdirSync for require a library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a legacy code for my express app that read all routes files in specific dir and require them in a loop. Notice this code cant be changed:

**app.js**

```
const normalizedRoutes = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/src/routes/')
  .map(routeFile => `/src/routes/${routeFile}`);

normalizedRoutes.forEach((normalizedRouteDir: string) => {
    require(normalizedRouteDir)(app);
})
```

Now, I want to combine a Server Side Rendered application with the code above, using some JSX in routes files.
My problem is because the routes files are loaded on run time webpack not recognize them when creating the bundle.js file.
Therefore there are not routes files in the `/src/routes/${routeFile}` and when I run the bundle.js file I get an error message of:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/******/build/src/routes/'`

(the stars are for hiding full path)

webpack configs:

***webpack.base.js***

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
    module: { //remain
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options:{
                    presets:[
                        '@babel/react',
                        ['@babel/env',{targets:{browsers:['last 2 versions']}}]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    }
};
```

***webpack.server.js***

```
const path = require('path')
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge')
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.js');
const webpackNodeexternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        main:"./app.ts",
    },
    resolve: { 
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts"],
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: true
    },
    output: { 
        libraryTarget: "commonjs",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },

    target: "node", 

    //Avoid put node modules of server when sending to browser
    externals: [webpackNodeexternals()]
   
}

module.exports = merge(baseConfig,config)
```

scripts from `package.json`:

```
"dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec \"node build/bundle.js\" ",
"dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
```

When I copy the route files (js files) to the build directory it works of course but that means I don't run webpack on these files and therefore I can't include JSX\es6 features inside these files.

So my question is:

1. Is there any possible way to make these requires identify by webpack/babel to add them to bundle.js and avoid the need for seperate files (bundle.js and routes files)
2. If we cant do it, how can I run webpack on a folder seperatly from the bundle.js output and create a route folder in the correct path but after processed by babel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Webpack` you can try using a programmatic interface of `babel`, and transpile the files before requiring them.

Here is the link https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core